# Nexus proxy for repo.maven.apache.org not working

Tags: apache, maven, nexus

I create a news proxy maven 2 in nexus for apache libs:
[image]

Then I changed my pom.xml as follow:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-public</id>
        <url>http://nexus.unc.nc/repository/maven-public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-releases</id>
        <url>http://nexus.unc.nc/repository/maven-releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-apache</id>
        <url>http://nexus.unc.nc/repository/maven-apache/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But it still downloads apache lib from internet:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ importparcoursup ---
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.pom (998 B at 2.0 kB/s)
```

whereas other libs are taken fro nexus:

```
Downloading from maven-public: http://nexus.unc.nc/repository/maven-public/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-mail/2.0.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-mail-2.0.6.RELEASE.pom
```

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the configuration of `central` repository is inherited from the [super POM](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.4/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html). You may try to override it as follows:

```
<repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <url>http://nexus.unc.nc/repository/maven-apache/</url>
</repository>
```

Or - this is a recommended solution - put a [mirror definition](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html) in `settings.xml`:

```
<settings>
  ...
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>company-central</id>
      <name>Company Central</name>
      <url>http://nexus.unc.nc/repository/maven-apache/</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  ...
</settings>
```